# How to implement a PHP script between NGINX reverse proxy server and website server?

Tags: nginx, php, reverse-proxy

How to implement a php script between reverse proxy server and the website server?

So it can go as follows:

`Domain -> reverse proxy server -> go trough php script -> upstream to website IP of server`

**Edit**: thorough description:

I want to set up a firewall simple page where in order to pass to the website you have to click on a button "go to website".

It is very important this middle page to be on the reverse proxy server. I want to store every unique IP that solves it and never show the page again. So how can I set the script to be between the reverse proxy server and the website server?

At the moment the domain name of the website is aimed at the IP of the NGINX reverse proxy which is upstreaming the IP of the server where the website is located.

Comment: Can you explain better your question?

Comment: @fox91 Yes, I will update the description.

Comment: I dont think you know the meaning of the words reverse proxy. You want a captive portal or transparent proxy. A reverse proxy is not designed to capture all traffic, only traffic already destined to a particular site.

Comment: @davidgo Thank you for the comment. I was not aware of the transparent proxy, if I make it as transparent proxy, will I bi able to run the script before it leads the user to the upstream IP where the website is located?

Comment: Yes, in principle. A transparent proxy simply intercepts all traffic on a given port for further handling. (What happens once its intercepted is up to the proxy software)

Comment: @davidgo And the question was, when this traffic is interacted, how to make it go trough a PHP script and than return to the back server?

Comment: And the answer is that it depends on the proxy.  What you are describing is a captive portal of which a transparent proxy is a part.

Comment: @davidgo My goal is to make this middle page and stop all traffic there and pass only real visitor. From what I understand I will not need a reverse proxy, but a captive portal. Right? Is there an article of something remotely close to this online? I am browsing forums left and right and can't seem to find anything I can start playing around with.

Comment: Correct. Maybe start by looking at Coovachilli. (I've not used it, but there are a fair few tutorials on it online)

Comment: @davidgo Thank you for the suggestion. Ill start there and will updating when I have something! :)